# Can I avoid returning a template return type of a function?

Tags: c++

I am building a priority que, and trying to make it a template class. When I pop, it must return type T. Is there a way to return nothing or a good practice to avoid a crash if there is nothing in the que?

Comment: throwing an exception would be reasonable.

Comment: Maybe look at `std::priority_queue` for inspiration?

Answer (score 4):

The expected behavior here would be to throw an exception. The user should check the queue for being empty before trying to pop. You could return null as well, but only if your type T never has a value of null, otherwise it is ambiguous if this is being returned because an error happened or because the next value in the queue was null.

Comment: I feel kind of bad for mentioning it, but `optional<T>` would effectively *make* it nullable. An exception really is better than trying to deal with returning an invalid value, though.

Comment: Returning a null or other trivial value may be not a good idear. If I instantiate priority_queue<CMyClass> , construct a instance and return it, which may cause unexpected result.

Comment: As a template class writer, you cannot make assumptions about the relation between type `T` and "null". "null" is at best a concept. `NULL` is a null **pointer** constant, and you can't assume `T` is a pointer. C++ is not Java, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are irrelevant to the question.

There are couple of common ways to deal with the situation:

1. Store the objects on the heap. Upon removal detach the object from the data structure and return reference (pointer) to it instead of the object itself. If the data structure is empty, return NULL.
2. Define your `pop` as valid only if the queue isn't empty. Thus the user will need to perform an emptiness check before invoking `pop` (need to provide `isEmpty` functionality). If this precondition isn't met, exception/error return is a valid treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a `pop` operation should [not](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/020163371x/supplements/Exception_Handling_Article.html) return a value. That's because the copy constructor for the returned type might throw an exception; if that happens, the value is gone from the queue and hasn't been copied anywhere, so it has simply disappeared.

Instead, there should be two operations: a `top` function that returns a reference to the object on the top of the data structure, and a `pop` function that removes the top element but doesn't return anything. If you look at `std::queue` you'll see the members `void pop()` and `reference front()` which returns a reference to the top element.

Now to get to your question. `<g>` Popping an empty queue is an error. In the standard library it produces undefined behavior. If you want to add code for error checking you should either throw an exception or abort the program. I'd lean toward the latter; if the calling code hasn't determined that there is an element to pop, it probably hasn't been written to handle an exception robustly. On the other hand, in a GUI, maybe it's appropriate to throw an exception that terminates the current operation; this would leave the application running and waiting for the next user request.